# How to decompress a GZIP file pulled from SFTP in Python3 the same way Mac OS's gunzip does it?

Tags: python, csv, ftp, gzip

Okay, I've been stuck on this one for hours which should have only taken a few minutes of work.

I have the following code which pulls a gzipped CSV file from a datastore:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import gzip
import csv

ftps = FTP_TLS('waws-prod.net')
ftps.login(user='foo', passwd='bar')

resp = ftps.retrbinary('RETR data/WFSIV0606201701.700.csv.gz', gzip.open('WFSIV0606201701.700.csv.gz', 'wb').write)
```

The file appears in the pwd, and I can even open my Mac Decompression tool, and the original CSV is decompressed perfectly.

However, if I try to decompress this file in using the gzip Library, i can't get a UTF8 encoded string to parse:

```
f=gzip.GzipFile('WFSIV0606201701.700.csv.gz', 'rb')
s = f.read()
```

I get what appears to be UTF8 bytestrings, however utf8 decoder can't parse the string.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

BUT! If i download directly from the SFTP server using FileZilla, and i do run the `gzip.GzipFile` code above, it reads it perfectly. Something must be wrong with my downloader/reader but i haven't a clue as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
resp = ftps.retrbinary('RETR data/WFSIV0606201701.700.csv.gz', gzip.open('WFSIV0606201701.700.csv.gz', 'wb').write)
```

This line downloads a compressed file, and then compresses it *again* when writing it to disk.

Replace `gzip.open(...).write` with `open(...).write` to write the compressed file directly.

Comment: Wow. Stupid me. Thanks!